# iPhone Localization - Get the phone's language code?

Tags: iphone, localization

I'm localizing my iPhone app for multiple languages, and in addition to changing some of the strings I need to change some backgrounds.  Is it possible to query the iPhone and get the user's language code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Take a look at NSLocale:

```
NSString   *language = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSString   *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

Answer (score 11):

solved my own question!

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
if (!language) {
   language = @"en";
}
NSLog(@"The device's specified language is %@", language);
```

Swift version :

```
var language : String! = "en"
if let lng = NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first {
  language = lng
}
print("The device's specified language is \(language)")
```