# How to change localization after an iPad app has been started

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, localization, internationalization

i am currently working on an iPad app (iOS SDK v3.2). The app is localized in several languages, i.e. english, german, russian, ...

I want the user to be able to switch the localization for some UI elements *after* the app has been started. What is the best way to achieve this? NSLocalizedString always chooses the locale defined in the system preferences, so that won't help.

Note: the localization is all done by using .strings files, there are no localized NIBs in my project.

To make the whole process more clear, here's an example:
When the app is started the UI is displayed in english. The user can select a different language from a UITableView and parts of the UI get updated with the chosen language.

Do i have to manually load the specific Localizable.strings file and parse it all the way through or is there a better option, to get the relevant strings?

Any helpful advice is appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 4):

I guess i found an answer to my own question:

```
NSLocale *selectedLocale; // defined in the classes interface
NSString *language = [selectedLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

self.textView.text = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Yadayada", @"Localizable", bundle, @"Yadayada comment");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @XCoder, that did work great.

However I do have an app BAD_EXC on the NSLocaleLanguageCode.

I got it solved using the method mentionned here:
[iPhone Localization - Get the phone's language code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031110/iphone-localization-get-the-phones-country-language-code)