# Xcode iOS Localization - trying to learn how to understand/use location codes

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have a US Phone and I'm localizing my app. I have set the preferences > General > International to French.

My app comes up in French. Great.. I used the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031110/iphone-localization-get-the-phones-country-language-code) to see the language codes.

The code is:

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
//NSString   *language = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];
//NSString   *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

However, the console comes back with en-US. I guess I was expecting fr-US. Can someone explain why it's "en"..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]`, you will get your currently selected language

Comment: Ah, that is interesting... I got: 2012-03-02  Locale is fr
language is en
countryCode is US

Answer (score 1):

language is different to region format.

Answer (score 1):

NSLocale is not related to language. NSLocale provides a way to tailor your programs behavior to the what is customary for particular regions. This includes formatting number, dates, and currency, for example.

> Locales encapsulate information about linguistic, cultural, and
>   technological conventions and standards. Examples of information
>   encapsulated by a locale include the symbol used for the decimal
>   separator in numbers and the way dates are formatted.
>
> Locales are typically used to provide, format, and interpret
>   information about and according to the user’s customs and preferences.
>   They are frequently used in conjunction with formatters (see Data
>   Formatting Guide).

[NSLocale currentLocale] depends on where the device is located, an dis independent of the language that you pick in your phone's settings.

As Audun said about getting the devices current language, you can get that from [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]. You can look at other members of that array, and it will show you the language seettings that were most recently used first (followed by all the other languages that the device supports, in no particular order, as far as I know).

Comment: By the way, I don't think there is a locale 'fr_US'. Try [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers] to get an array of all the locale identifiers. There are quite a few of them.

Comment: Maybe it's my brain, but I find the Apple docs hard to comprehend. Unix in the old days was easier for me.. I do better with examples and clear language. And so, I very much appreciate your explanation.